# Syntax error in ruby using watir

Tags: ruby, watir

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekvPD.jpg)

I'm making a progrma that goes on instagram and sub to someone. I don't see any errors but when i run it it says syntax error unexpected tSTRING.
I've looked up and can't fin what i've done wrong.

If anyone could help me. thx

```
require 'watir'

username = "videos2fdp"
password = "no pass"
user = "videos_folle"

browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
browser.goto"https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/"

puts "Logging in ..."
browser.text_field(:name => "username").set"#{username}"
browser.text_field(:name => "password").set"#{password}"

browser.button(:class => '_ah57t _84y62 _i46jh _rmr7s').click
sleep(2)

browser.goto "instagram.com/#{user}/"

if browser.button(:class => '_ah57t _84y62 _frcv2 _rmr7s').exist ?
    puts "Following #{user}"
    browser.button(:class => '_ah57t _84y62 _frcv2 _rmr7s').click
end


sleep (3)

if browser.button(:class => '_ah57t _6y2ah _frcv2 _rmr7s').exist ?
    puts "Unfollowing #{user}"
    browser.button(:class => '_ah57t _6y2ah _frcv2 _rmr7s').click

end






sleep(360)
```

Comment: include the program here , let me check with my editor.

Comment: There's an error at x:485, y:275 in your image. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Stefan He is using `exists ?` instead of `exists?`, Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Rajagopalan indeed, did you look up the coordinates? :-)

Comment: @Stefan Thank you, I don't know how to find coordinates.

Comment: @Rajagopalan yeah, my comment was meant as a subtle pointer for the OP to post code instead of images.

Comment: @Stefan ha ha , you find a nice way of saying :) Thanks for pointing him out!

Comment: @Stefan thank you! you literally made my day.

Comment: srry guys i edited it and added the code

Comment: @Stefan by the way i changed exist ? to exist? and nothing changed i still have the same error

Comment: In which place are you getting the error? Can you able to login?

Comment: Able to click the button after entering the username and password?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, this is the corrected code, Try now

You are misplacing `?` instead of `exist?` you are using `exist ?`

```
require 'watir'

username = "videos2fdp"
password = "9519516477Am"
user = "videos_folle"

browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
browser.goto "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/"

puts "Logging in ..."
browser.text_field(:name => "username").set "#{username}"
browser.text_field(:name => "password").set "#{password}"

#browser.button(:text => 'Log in').click
browser.button(:class => "_qv64e       _gexxb _4tgw8     _njrw0   ".split).click
sleep(2)

browser.goto "instagram.com/#{user}/"

if browser.button(:class => '_ah57t _84y62 _frcv2 _rmr7s'.split).exist?
  puts "Following #{user}"
  browser.button(:class => '_ah57t _84y62 _frcv2 _rmr7s'.split).click
end


sleep (3)

if browser.button(:class => '_ah57t _6y2ah _frcv2 _rmr7s'.split).exist?
  puts "Unfollowing #{user}"
  browser.button(:class => '_ah57t _6y2ah _frcv2 _rmr7s'.split).click

end


sleep(360)
```

Comment: Now i get an error in my terminal that repeats to the infinit saying : 2018-04-26 09:55:04 WARN Watir [DEPRECATION] Using the :class locator to locate multiple classes with a String value is deprecated. Use Array instead.

Comment: @Gaspargg Okay, I updated the code for button click, Can you take my code and trying executing again?

Comment: yes thanks a lot but it seems watir can't locate the button : C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/watir-6.10.3/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:664:in `rescue in element_call': timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for #<Wat
ir::Button: located: false; {:text=>"Log in", :tag_name=>"button"}> to be located; Maybe look in an iframe? (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)

Comment: never mind i changed the text target to a class and it works

Comment: @Gaspargg I have updated the code with class, it works for me!